# Model Validation for Date in ASP.NET MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, datetime, razor

In my **ASP.Net mvc3 Razor** project i have to implement date validation.My format for the same was dd-mm-yyyy.i tried in different way but none works fine .I need a simple one.My question is is there any regular expression for the same.

**My Model Code**

```
{
    [Table("tbl_Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {

        [Key]public int EmpId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Employee First Name is Required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Employee Last Name is Required")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age{get;set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DateOfJoining { get; set; }
        public string EducationalQuali { get; set; }
        public string Experience { get; set; }
        public string Others { get; set; }


    }
```

**View Code**

```
<div class="col-lg-10" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Date/Month/Year" })</div>
```

I have used one placeholder to show the user that ""this was the format".But it is also creating problem from the user.how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decorate the model property with **[RegularExpression Attribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)** with the following pattern,

```
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$
```

It will validate following date formats,

- `dd/MM/yyyy`
- `dd-MM-yyyy`

The property value will be set valid if it satisfies the pattern. You can set the custom error message in `ErrorMessage` property.

```
[RegularExpression("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /](19|20)[0-9][0-9]$", ErrorMessage="")]
public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
```

This works well on both server and client side. For client side which is better for good user experience, do not forget to turn on the unobtrusive validation and include `jquery.validation.js` and `jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js` in your web page. :)